# How can i get the name of the Sub-list that contains the n-th Sub-Sub-list?

Tags: r

Sorry for the confusing title, i don't know how to phrase it to make my problem clearer.

Let's assume i have the following Lists:

```
a <- list(list(c("a","b")),list(c("c","d")))
b <- list(list(c("e","f")))
c <- list(list(c("a","b")),list(c("e","f")))

# a,b and c are saved inside named lists:
d <- list(a,b,c)
e <- list(b,c,a,a)
names(d) <- c("List X","List Number Y","List Number Z")
names(e) <- c("List Number W","List X","List Number Y","List Number Z")
```

What i need is a function f, that is given a List (like d and e) and an integer n and it returns the name of the sublist that contains the nth sublist. It becomes clearer if you look at my example:

Let's see how "d" looks like:

```
> d
$`List X`
$`List X`[[1]]
$`List X`[[1]][[1]]
[1] "a" "b"


$`List X`[[2]]
$`List X`[[2]][[1]]
[1] "c" "d"



$`List Number Y`
$`List Number Y`[[1]]
$`List Number Y`[[1]][[1]]
[1] "e" "f"



$`List Number Z`
$`List Number Z`[[1]]
$`List Number Z`[[1]][[1]]
[1] "a" "b"


$`List Number Z`[[2]]
$`List Number Z`[[2]][[1]]
[1] "e" "f"
```

so `function(d,3)` would return "List Number Y", cause the third Sub-Sublist is contained inside that List

`function(d,1)` and `function(d,2)` would return "List Number X" and

`function(d,4)` and `function(d,5)` would return "List Number Z"

Is there an elegant way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foo = function(mylist, n){
    names(mylist)[which(cumsum(lengths(mylist)) >= n)[1]]
}

sapply(1:5, function(i) foo(d, i))
#[1] "List X"        "List X"        "List Number Y" "List Number Z" "List Number Z"

foo(d, n = 7)
#[1] NA
```